# how to add the external web site as personal app inside the team's using teams manifest, the web site is using SAML based auth for sign in the user

Tags: microsoft-teams, saml, manifest.json, microsoft-teams-js

After the Deployment of manifest file in the team admin center, when i load the app in team's it is showing following error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3CEH.png)

Any help? I went through the Microsoft document, there it was mentioned SAML based authentication not supported in team's tab app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teams tabs currently only support OAuth 2.0 authentication. Unfortunately, SAML-based authentication is not directly compatible with Teams personal tabs.

To resolve this issue, you'll need to modify your application to support OAuth 2.0 authentication instead of SAML.

[image]

Comment: Even if I try with "login.salesforce.com," the webpage is still failing to load in Teams. Any help on this?

Comment: Login pages don't render in iFrames, as a safeguard against clickjacking. Your authentication logic needs to use a method other than redirect. For example, use token-based or cookie-based authentication.
Please refer the following prerequisites: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements